# how to get the output in float format while adding the two double values datatypes

Tags: c#

```
double d = 4.0;
double e = 4.0;

Console.WriteLine(d + e);
```

output is 8 but need to get output as 8.0

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what should be used to get 8.0 @jonasH

Comment: @S.Sathiesh give output format to it

Comment: If you want some concrete number of fractional digits you can use one of [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) or a [custom one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Comment: output should be as 8.0@ShubhamSrivastava

Comment: Here's one way to to it: `double result = d + e; Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("0.0"));`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify the [formatting of the value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

For example

```
 Console.WriteLine((d + e).ToString("N1"));
```

Comment: what the n1 here means

Comment: @ s.sathiesh read the link

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0}", d + e));`

[Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: thank you its gives correct output